# display a context menu when clicking on tabBar

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I have a weird requirment to accomplish. Let say I have a tabHost with 3 tabs. And let say the second tab is curently displayed. What I need  to do is - when clicking on the third tab to display a context menu. The context menu needs to be displayed in the activity from tab 2.

**IMPORTANT** So, when I click on the third tab I must not go to another activity, I must stay at the current activity(from tab 2) and display a context menu also.

Hope I made myself clear. Thank you!

Comment: check answer as given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204729/display-a-contextmenu-when-clicking-a-tab-in-the-same-screen-with-the-tabs/11208500#11208500

Answer (score 0):

simple demo example as given at below check it make some changes according to ur requirement

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;

public class Tab_exActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    // this.myhost = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.);

    // this.myhost.setup();
     final TabHost tabHost=getTabHost(); 
     // The activity TabHost
     TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
     Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

     // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
     intent = new Intent().setClass(this, tabactivity1.class);

     // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
     spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Home",
                       res.getDrawable(R.drawable.act1))
                   .setContent(intent);
     tabHost.addTab(spec);

     // Do the same for the other tabs
     intent = new Intent().setClass(this, tabactivity2.class);
     spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Refresh",
                       res.getDrawable(R.drawable.act2))
                   .setContent(intent);
     tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // intent = new Intent().setClass(this, tabactivity3.class);
     spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Search",
                       res.getDrawable(R.drawable.act3))
                   .setContent(intent);

     tabHost.addTab(spec);
     tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){

         public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

         if (tabId.equals("songs")){
             System.out.println("44444");
             View v = tabHost.getCurrentView();
             registerForContextMenu(v);
             v.showContextMenu();
         }

         }});


    // openContextMenu(spec);
    // tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
@Override  
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");  
} 
}
```